# Signal slot in qt giving error

Tags: c++, qt

I have wrote a simple signal - slot. where i member objects signal is connected to slot of the class. I gets error

I have given the code below... If I keep the connect in the constructor then also i get error.

```
#ifndef COUNTER_H
#define COUNTER_H
#include <QObject>
#include <QTextEdit>

class Counter : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Counter()
    {
        m_value = 0;
    }

    int value() const
    {
        return m_value;
    }

public slots:
    void setValue(int value);
    void callSetValue();

signals:
    void valueChanged(int newValue);

private:
    int m_value;
    QTextEdit m_text;
};

#endif // COUNTER_H
```

//counter.cpp

```
#include "counter.h"

void Counter::setValue(int value)
{
    QObject::connect (&m_text, SIGNAL(textChanged()), this, SLOT(callSetValue()));

    qDebug("setValue invoked");
    if (value != m_value)
    {
        m_value = value;
        m_text.setText("hai");
        emit valueChanged(value);
        qDebug("emited signal");
    }
}

void callSetValue()
{
    qDebug("callSetValue() invoked");
}
```

gives me error "undefined reference to 'Counter::callSetValue()'

Comment: You should not edit your question like that. The answers will lose their meaning. Ask a new question instead.

Answer (score 5):

At the bottom of `counter.cpp` change

```
void callSetValue()
```

to

```
void Counter::callSetValue()
```

Comment: Why I can't add the connect statement in the constructor of the class?

Comment: You can add the connect statement in the constructor. The error you have is linker warning, you define stand-alone function `void callSetValue()`, but do not define member function of `Counter` class, that's why the error.

Comment: I have a similar error as the previous.. can tell why error comes in it?

Comment: Did you add linker dependency on QtNetwork library? It's unclear how you build your project. If you use `.pro` file, please show the line starting with `QT +=` from it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try re-running qmake? The code for signals may not have been generated if you modified signals or slots without running qmake again.